# How to return correctly formatted pandas dataframe from apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

Say we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

years = [2005, 2006]
location = ['city', 'suburb']
dft = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [years[np.random.randint(0, 1+1)] for _ in range(100)],
    'location': [location[np.random.randint(0, 1+1)] for _ in range(100)],
    'days_to_complete': np.random.randint(100, high=600, size=100),
    'cost_in_millions': np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=100)
})
```

Groupby year and location and then apply a function like the following:

```
def get_custom_summary(group):
    gt_200 = group.days_to_complete > 200
    lt_200 = group.days_to_complete < 200

    avg_days_gt200 = group[gt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
    avg_cost_gt200 = group[gt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

    avg_days_lt200 = group[lt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
    avg_cost_lt200 = group[lt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

    lt_200_prop = lt_200.sum() / (gt_200.sum() + lt_200.sum())

    return pd.DataFrame({
        'gt_200': {'AVG_DAYS': avg_days_gt200, 'AVG_COST': avg_cost_gt200}, 
        'lt_200': {'avg_days': avg_days_lt200, 'avg_cost': avg_cost_lt200},
        'lt_200_prop' : lt_200_prop
    })

result = dft.groupby(['year', 'location']).apply(get_custom_summary)
```

Calling unstack(2) on the result we get the following output:

```
print(result.unstack(2))

                 gt_200                                 lt_200                             lt_200_prop                              
               AVG_COST    AVG_DAYS avg_cost avg_days AVG_COST AVG_DAYS  avg_cost avg_days    AVG_COST  AVG_DAYS  avg_cost  avg_days
year location                                                                                                                       
2005 city      4.818182  415.636364      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  7.250000   165.50    0.153846  0.153846  0.153846  0.153846
     suburb    5.631579  336.631579      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  5.166667   140.50    0.240000  0.240000  0.240000  0.240000
2006 city      4.130435  396.913043      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  5.750000   150.75    0.258065  0.258065  0.258065  0.258065
     suburb    5.294118  392.823529      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  1.000000   128.00    0.055556  0.055556  0.055556  0.055556
```

For the columns `gt_200` and `lt_200` a call to `dropna(axis=1)` will remove the columns filled with NaN, but the `lt_200_prop` column is still stuck with the wrong column names. How could I return a DataFrame from get_custom_summary that doesn't broadcast (if that's the right word) the subcolumns (`AVG_COST`, `AVG_DAYS`, `avg_cost`, `avg_days`) to the columns (`gt_200`, `lt_200`, `lt_200_prop`)?

EDIT:

Desired output:

```
                 gt_200               lt_200          lt_200_prop                              
               AVG_COST    AVG_DAYS avg_cost avg_days
year location                                                                                                                       
2005 city      4.818182  415.636364 7.250000   165.50    0.153846
     suburb    5.631579  336.631579 5.166667   140.50    0.240000
2006 city      4.130435  396.913043 5.750000   150.75    0.258065
     suburb    5.294118  392.823529 1.000000   128.00    0.055556
```

Comment: Can you add desired output?

Comment: @jezrael just added desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a Dataframe with columns set equal to a MultiIndex.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_multi_index(ordered_dict):
    length = len(list(ordered_dict.values())[0])

    for k in ordered_dict:
        assert(len(ordered_dict[k]) == length)

    names = list()
    arrays = list()
    for k in ordered_dict:
        names.append(k)
        arrays.append(np.array(ordered_dict[k]))

    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=names) 

def get_custom_summary(group):
    gt_200 = group.days_to_complete > 200
    lt_200 = group.days_to_complete < 200

    avg_days_gt_200 = group[gt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
    avg_cost_gt_200 = group[gt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

   avg_days_lt_200 = group[lt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
   avg_cost_lt_200 = group[lt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

   lt_200_prop = lt_200.sum() / (gt_200.sum() + lt_200.sum())

   ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
   ordered_dict['first'] = ['lt_200', 'lt_200', 'gt_200', 'gt_200', 'lt_200_prop']
   ordered_dict['second'] = ['avg_cost', 'avg_days', 'AVG_COST', 'AVG_DAYS', 'prop']

   data = [[avg_cost_lt_200, avg_days_lt_200, avg_cost_gt_200, avg_days_gt_200, lt_200_prop]]
   return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=get_multi_index(ordered_dict))
```

Get and print result:

```
result = dft.groupby(['year', 'location']).apply(get_custom_summary).xs(0, level=2)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
first            lt_200                gt_200             lt_200_prop
second         avg_cost    avg_days  AVG_COST    AVG_DAYS        prop
year location                                                        
2005 city      7.555556  135.444444  5.300000  363.750000    0.310345
     suburb    5.000000  137.333333  5.555556  444.222222    0.250000
2006 city      6.250000  169.000000  4.714286  422.380952    0.160000
     suburb    4.428571  133.142857  4.333333  445.666667    0.318182
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is use same column names in function `get_custom_summary` in `gt_200` and `lt_200` and then rename it by function [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and add last custom column name `col`.

But there is `MultiIndex`, so you need create new by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
years = [2005, 2006]
location = ['city', 'suburb']
np.random.seed(1234)
dft = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [years[np.random.randint(0, 1+1)] for _ in range(100)],
    'location': [location[np.random.randint(0, 1+1)] for _ in range(100)],
    'days_to_complete': np.random.randint(100, high=600, size=100),
    'cost_in_millions': np.random.randint(1, high=10, size=100)
})

def get_custom_summary(group):
    gt_200 = group.days_to_complete > 200
    lt_200 = group.days_to_complete < 200

    avg_days_gt200 = group[gt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
    avg_cost_gt200 = group[gt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

    avg_days_lt200 = group[lt_200].days_to_complete.mean()
    avg_cost_lt200 = group[lt_200].cost_in_millions.mean()

    lt_200_prop = (lt_200).sum() / ((gt_200).sum() + (lt_200).sum())

    return pd.DataFrame({
        'gt_200': {'AVG_DAYS': avg_days_gt200, 'AVG_COST': avg_cost_gt200}, 
        'lt_200': {'AVG_DAYS': avg_days_lt200, 'AVG_COST': avg_cost_lt200},
         'lt_200_prop' : lt_200_prop
    })
```

```
result = dft.groupby(['year', 'location']).apply(get_custom_summary).unstack(2)
#drop last column with duplicates values
result = result.drop(result.columns[[-1]], axis=1)

#rename columns names in level 1
a = (result.columns.get_level_values(1))
level1 = a[:2].union(a[2:4].str.lower().union(['col']))
cols = list(zip(result.columns.get_level_values(0),level1))
result.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)

print (result)
                 gt_200                lt_200             lt_200_prop
               AVG_COST    AVG_DAYS  avg_cost    avg_days         col
year location                                                        
2005 city      5.238095  392.095238  5.500000  144.666667    0.222222
     suburb    4.428571  427.095238  4.000000  167.666667    0.125000
2006 city      4.368421  406.789474  4.571429  150.142857    0.269231
     suburb    4.000000  439.062500  4.142857  145.142857    0.304348
```

---

Simplier solution is remove columns:

```
result = dft.groupby(['year', 'location']).apply(get_custom_summary).unstack(2)
#drop last 3 column, then drop NaN columns
result = result.drop(result.columns[[-1, -2, -3]], axis=1).dropna(axis=1)
print (result)
                 gt_200                lt_200             lt_200_prop
               AVG_COST    AVG_DAYS  avg_cost    avg_days    AVG_COST
year location                                                        
2005 city      5.238095  392.095238  5.500000  144.666667    0.222222
     suburb    4.428571  427.095238  4.000000  167.666667    0.125000
2006 city      4.368421  406.789474  4.571429  150.142857    0.269231
     suburb    4.000000  439.062500  4.142857  145.142857    0.304348
```

Comment: Although your solution does work in this case, it seems it could get messy if we called get_custom_summary on 10 columns with varied nesting. I did take your idea for the MultiIndex.from_tuples, but I used it inside the apply function instead of outside and so far it seems to work pretty. I'll post what I did in an answer.